# GetType on generic types

Tags: vb.net, generics

I'm trying register presenters with Windsor using the convention based method but trying to do this in VB.NET, but the problem is it does not want to compile this statement:

```
Dim type = GetType(AbstractPresenter(Of))
```

I am getting : Too few type arguments to AbstractPresenter(Of TView, TPresenter)

Which I don't understand because this is a valid statement according to [question](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35856120/dynamic-instantiation-with-generic-parameters.aspx). Also showing valid in other C# to VB.NET converters when converting typeof(AbstractPresenter<>).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two type arguments, and you need to specify this, just as you would do for multi-dimensional arrays:

```
Dim type = GetType(AbstractPresenter(Of ,))
```

Looks weird, but now the compiler knows that `AbstractPresenter` expects two type arguments.

By the way, C# has the same requirement. So the above would be written as:

```
var type = typeof(AbstractPresenter<,>);
```